# duplicate row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 excel files:

[file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5pim.png)

[file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXz0l.png)

Scope:

Need to check if in file2 exists UniQ ID from file1 and add to file1 column 'Event'. If the event doubles then the row doubles in file 1

Expected result:
[final file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkNnb.png)

What I tried:

```
file1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
file2= pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')


for index_tt, item_tt in file1 [file1 ['UniQ ID'].notnull()].iterrows():
     for index_c, item_c in file2.iterrows():
        if item_tt['UniQ ID'] in item_c['UniQ ID']:
            file1.loc[index_tt, 'Event'] = item_c['Event']
            break
```

This code above does not duplicate the rows in file1  if there are multiple events but only copies the first one. How could I multiply the row if there are several events with the same ID?Like in the final file

Thank you for your support!!

Comment: Welcome on SO! Does this help:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html ?

Answer (score 0):

like this maybe?

```
file1 = pd.merge(file1,file2,on="UniQ ID", how="left")
```